# Processing an image to sepia tone in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I need help figuring out how to convert an image to sepia. This is what I have so far..but it only changes everything to black and white colors with a very small tint of brown. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong :(

```
import image

def convertSepia(input_image):
    grayscale_image = image.EmptyImage(input_image.getWidth(), input_image.getHeight())

    for col in range(input_image.getWidth()):
        for row in range(input_image.getHeight()):
            p = input_image.getPixel(col, row)

            R = p.getRed()
            G = p.getGreen()
            B = p.getBlue()

            newR = (R * 0.393 + G * 0.769 + B * 0.189)
            newG = (R * 0.349 + G * 0.686 + B * 0.168)
            newB = (R * 0.272 + G * 0.534 + B * 0.131)

            newpixel = image.Pixel(newR, newG, newB)
            grayscale_image.setPixel(col, row, newpixel)

    sepia_image = image.EmptyImage(input_image.getWidth(), input_image.getHeight())
    for col in range(input_image.getWidth()):
        for row in range(input_image.getHeight()):
            p = grayscale_image.getPixel(col, row)
            red = p.getRed()
            if red > 140:
                val = (R * 0.393 + G * 0.769 + B * 0.189)
            else:
                val = 0
            green = p.getGreen()
            if green > 140:
                val = (R * 0.349 + G * 0.686 + B * 0.168)
            else:
                val = 0
            blue = p.getBlue()
            if blue > 140:
                val = (R * 0.272 + G * 0.534 + B * 0.131)
            else:
                val = 0

            newpixel = image.Pixel(val, val, val)
            sepia_image.setPixel(col, row, newpixel)
    return sepia_image


win = image.ImageWin() img = image.Image("luther.jpg")

sepia_img = convertSepia(img) sepia_img.draw(win)

win.exitonclick()
```

Any more tips as to where to go from here? Thanks :)

Comment: It seems to me that the main issue is here: `newpixel = image.Pixel(val, val, val)`. If all pixel channels are same, it becomes greyscale.

Answer (score 1):

Your gray level image is not a gray level image. In a gray level image all three channels `r`,`g`,`b` have the same value.

Open paint and try it to verify if your code makes sense.

Fix these lines:

```
newR = (R * 0.393 + G * 0.769 + B * 0.189)
newG = (R * 0.349 + G * 0.686 + B * 0.168)
newB = (R * 0.272 + G * 0.534 + B * 0.131)
```

Simply use the mean of `r`,`g`,`b` and put it into `newR`, `newG` and `newG`.

There are some weighted means as well. Just Google for RGB to intensity formulas.

Comment: So am I supposed to convert it to grey scale first? And what's wrong with the values of my newR, newG, and newB? I'm so confused :^(

Comment: @KaileeCollins why else would you name the variable grayscale_image?
the problem with your values is that they won't result in a gray scale image.

Comment: maybe the naming just confused me. what your code does is that it will transfer an RGB image into a sepia image that is called grayscale_image for whatever reason. then it will create a gray scale image named sepia_img. I fully understand your confusion :)

Comment: Does every pixel need to be between rgb 0,0,0 and rgb 255,255,255 for this to work?

Comment: @Richard sorry I'm no longer helping here, since moderators punished me for informing people about things they don't know and for suggesting people to learn basics befor getting into advanced problems. it appears this is considered rude in countries like the US...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert image to sepia by just manipulating the pixel values. The following is the code(Disclaimer : Taken from [this](https://www.yabirgb.com/sepia_filter/) article.)

```
from PIL import Image

def sepia(image_path:str)->Image:
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    width, height = img.size

    pixels = img.load() # create the pixel map

    for py in range(height):
        for px in range(width):
            r, g, b = img.getpixel((px, py))

            tr = int(0.393 * r + 0.769 * g + 0.189 * b)
            tg = int(0.349 * r + 0.686 * g + 0.168 * b)
            tb = int(0.272 * r + 0.534 * g + 0.131 * b)

            if tr > 255:
                tr = 255

            if tg > 255:
                tg = 255

            if tb > 255:
                tb = 255

            pixels[px, py] = (tr,tg,tb)

    return img
```

Original Image [image]

Sepia Image [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution that do not require conversion to grayscale before sepia. I used the given formula for sepia:

```
newR = (R × 0.393 + G × 0.769 + B × 0.189)
newG = (R × 0.349 + G × 0.686 + B × 0.168)
newB = (R × 0.272 + G × 0.534 + B × 0.131)
```

Full code:

```
import image

img= image.Image("luther.jpg")
win=image.ImageWin(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())
img.draw(win)
img.setDelay(1,100)

for row in range(img.getHeight()):
    for col in range(img.getWidth()):
        p=img.getPixel(col,row)
        R= p.getRed()
        G= p.getGreen()
        B= p.getBlue()
        newR = 0.393*R + 0.769*G + 0.189*B
        newG = 0.349*R + 0.686*G + 0.168*B
        newB = 0.272*R + 0.534*G + 0.131*B
        newpixel= image.Pixel(newR,newG,newB)
        img.setPixel(col, row, newpixel)
        
img.draw(win)
win.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

With `numpy` vectorization, the implementation can be made much faster. Consider the following code that compares the `numpy`'s vectorized implementation with `PIL`'s loopy one, both of them  producing the same output image (using the same turtle input image by @Trect). As can be seen from the below output, the `numpy` implementation is *36* times faster than `PIL`'s, for the given input image.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from time import time
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def sepia_filter_PIL(image_path):
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    width, height = img.size
    pixels = img.load() # create the pixel map
    for py in range(height):
        for px in range(width):
            r, g, b = img.getpixel((px, py))
            pixels[px, py] = (min(255, int(0.393 * r + 0.769 * g + 0.189 * b)), \
                              min(255, int(0.349 * r + 0.686 * g + 0.168 * b)), \
                              min(255, int(0.272 * r + 0.534 * g + 0.131 * b)))
    return img


def sepia_filter_np(image_path):
    im = plt.imread(image_path)
    im = im / im.max()    
    R, G, B = im[...,0], im[...,1], im[...,2]
    im_out = np.dstack((0.393 * R + 0.769 * G + 0.189 * B, \
                        0.349 * R + 0.686 * G + 0.168 * B, \
                        0.272 * R + 0.534 * G + 0.131 * B))
    im_out = np.clip(im_out, 0, 1)
    return (255*im_out).astype(np.uint8)

img_path = 'images/turtle.jpg'
start = time()
im_out_np = sepia_filter_np(img_path) 
# time (np): 0.327577 sec
print('time (np): {:03f} sec'.format(time() - start))
start = time()
im_out_PIL = sepia_filter_PIL(img_path) 
print('time (PIL): {:03f} sec'.format(time() - start))
# time (PIL): 11.972195 sec
im, im_out_PIL = plt.imread(img_path), np.array(im_out_PIL)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,7))
plt.imshow(np.hstack((im, im_out_np, im_out_PIL))), plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]